# trouble in applying a function to selected columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python programming. so, what i want to achieve is basically fill all the na values in columns that are object type with their modes.

```
object_columns=['A1','A4','A5','A6','A7']#these are object types columns

#wrote this function
def find_mode_fill(x):
    return data[x].fillna(data[x].mode()[0])
```

I tried doing it in few ways which did not turn out to be correct.

1-

```
data=data.apply(lambda x: data[x].fillna(data[x].mode()[0]) if x in object_columns else x)
```

2-

```
data[object_columns]=data[object_columns].apply(find_mode_fill)
```

but, when i do use my function and apply it one by one it works

data['A1']=find_mode_fill('A1')

data['A2']=find_mode_fill('A2')
.
.
and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think apply function is not proper for your problem. 
Try this.

```
for col in object_columns:
    mode_value = df[col].mode()[0]
    df[col][df[col].isnull()] = mode_value
```

Comment: can you explain why apply is not a correct choice in performing this operation? I want to understand so that next time i don't make the same mistake.

Comment: pandas apply is useful when each value in a column enters a function, but is not useful when some representative value (in this case, mode) should be calculated because the representative value can be calculated using every value.